# Order-independency of Nonterminals in EBNF Grammar Spec

Tags: grammar, markup, ebnf

I have created a simple markup language that consists of simpe tags to write my blog texts. I write my blog post in that language and convert them into Html by a compiler.

User can specify the document language and that if the document supports the multilanguage? The document can only have two language *"Turkish (tr)"* and *"English (en)"*.

According to that, the document looks like the followings.

```
#lang en
#mul yes

And other tags and content...
```

```
#lang tr
#mul yes

And other tags and content...
```

```
#lang en
#mul no

And other tags and content...
```

And the grammar for it is as the following using EBNF notation.

```
YesNo = "yes" | "no"
Doclanguage = #lang "tr" | "en" 
Multilingual = #mul YesNo

DocumentHeader = Doclanguage Multilingual
```

However, I want `Doclanguage` and `Multilingual` to be independent of the order. Obviously, one can transform the grammar to the below.

```
YesNo = "yes" | "no"
Doclanguage = #lang "tr" | "en" 
Multilingual = #mul YesNo

DocumentHeader = Doclanguage Multilingual | Multilingual Doclanguage
```

But what if I have more than two nonterminal at the header? Say four or more, for example. When the case being that, it is also hard to write parsing function for such a grammar. **Is there way of writing such a grammar more structurely**?